# Is it possible to set quality in Image Intervention for WebP images?

Tags: php, laravel, webp, intervention, image-quality

I want to convert jpg to webp and set the quality to 50 (as an example). But the Image Intervention only supports the quality parameter only for jpg files.

> quality (optional)
>
> Define the quality of the encoded image optionally.
> Data ranging from 0 (poor quality, small file) to 100 (best quality,
> big file). Quality is only applied if you're encoding JPG format since
> PNG compression is lossless and does not affect image quality.
> Default: 90.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

As specified in docs: https://image.intervention.io/v2/api/encode
You can encode the image in given format and given image quality.

```
$webp = Image::make('public/foo.png')->encode('webp', 75);
```

I did this today and worked as expected. Try to encode both qualities 80 and 100 and you will note the size difference, also a quality difference if you set it under 80

Comment: Have you read the `quality` section? You mean they have written something wrong there? I tested the one you mentioned, no luck!

Answer (score 0):

$webp = Image::make('public/foo.png')->encode('webp', 75); this only applies when you converting to .jpg from .png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).